# Обработка исключений

Tags: c++, visual-studio, обработка-ошибок

Почему исключения не обрабатываются?

```
try
{
func();
}
catch(...)
{
std::cout << "error";
}
```

Делаю отладку в VS, компилятор говорит нарушение прав доступа при чтении. Жму продолжить. В некоторых случаях у меня выводит "error" то есть мой обработчик исключений.

А в некоторых, просто появляются новые окна компилятор с такой же ошибкой. И мой обработчик исключений не выполняется.

Можно ли сделать, чтобы всегда выполнялся только мой обработчик?

Comment: Покажи больше кода. Из того что ты написал у тебя рабочий пример.
А вот ошибка нарушение прав доступа при чтении. Это скорее всего недопустимая работа с памятью. (выход за границы, переполнение и пр.)

Comment: я думаю, что Вы понимаете, что некоторые ошибки сложно перехватить. Например, если из-за кривого кода был расстрелян стек, то хорошо ещё, если система уберет приложение самостоятельно.

У отладчика (коим студия является по совместительству) есть больше возможностей для перехвата исключений.

Comment: Поймите, try/catch не защищает от ошибок. Выход индекса за границы диапазона, использование неинициализированной переменной, ссылка на локальную переменную мёртвой функции — и никакой try/catch не поможет. try/catch ловит **лишь** исключения.

Ваша ошибка говорит о том, что память разрушена. Где вы её разрушили — мы не знаем, в показанном коде этого нет.

---
Подождите. Вы бросаете исключения **через границу DLL**?

Comment: @Николай Смирнов: В C++ это не так, при нарушении безопасности поведение непредсказуемо по стандарту. В других языках (C#, например), большинство ошибок является «ловимыми» исключениями, кроме совсем уж тяжёлых (stack overflow, execution engine failure, ...).

Comment: @Николай Смирнов: Ради производительности. И для удобства оптимизирующих компиляторов.

Пример: вот вы завели переменную и не инициализировали её. И передали её адрес другой функции. Допустим, вы знаете, что та функция её инициализирует. В языках типа C# вам такое не разрешат, т. к. компилятор не может выяснить, не будет ли доступа к неинициализированной переменной. В C++ ответственность лежит на вас. Если та функция на самом деле не инициализирует переменную (например, по ошибке), может случиться что угодно. Вас не заставят инициализировать, т. к. это может быть ненужным.

Comment: А можно как то вызвать обработчик, когда компилятор в режиме отладки определяет ошибку - которую нельзя поймать try-catch?

1) То есть он нашел ошибку, но мне нужно знать значения некоторых переменных, чтобы её устранить. А так отладчик просто показывает место ошибки и всё. И получается нужно гадать и долго искать что там может быть.

2) Можно ли в visual studio вставить код, выполнение которого можно включать и отключать в режиме отладки?

------------------
Есть книги по отладке в VS? Где прямо обо всех проблемах С++ рассказывается подробно и как устранять? В том числе много потоков?

Comment: @Николай Смирнов: Нет, никак. Эта ошибка означает, что программа уже умерла, и реанимации не подлежит. Исправить надо в коде, не допуская ошибок.

1) Если вас интересует состояние программы на момент вылета — воспользуйтесь отладчиком, поставьте breakpoint перед точкой вылета, проанализируйте, что идёт не так. Если эта точка программы выполняется много раз — попробуйте вместо этого отладочную печать.

2) например, заведите глобальную переменную `debug_mode` типа `bool` (не забудьте инициализировать!), и пишите: `if (debug_mode) { ... }`.

Comment: Ошибка связана с указателем void.
Не к тому типу приводиться.(там структура где только enum type и указатель void)
Исправить можно если копаться где задаётся. Я так и делаю сейчас.

Но мне интересно, как просмотреть значения переменных, которые рядом находяться, на тот момент когда отладчик определяет ошибку. Получается это вообще не возможно?

Comment: Почему невозможно. В некоторых ситуациях ещё как возможно. Но если память побита, то часть данных будет неверная или искаженная. В студии я имею мало опыта, но с помощью gdb и корок (core файлов) удавалось разобраться с многими неприятными падениями.

Comment: Теперь понял.
Студия в некоторых местах показывает значения переменных если навести мышь.
Значит дело в битой памяти.

Иногда значения показываются неверно, иногда верно, иногда при наведнеии вообще ничего не показывается. Было не понятно отчего так. Казалось, что сама студия сбоит. Ну а нет книги, где отладка подробно рассмотрена с примерами ошибок и как их пытаться исправлять? Можно и на английском, если на русском нет.

Comment: Иногда, компилятор может оптимизировать переменную и просто выбросить ее. Поэтому, при наведении на нее в отладчике, ничего не будет выведено.

Исправлять можно по разному. Мой любимый способ заключается в следующем. Вначале анализируется код и делаются оценки на значение различных переменных. Потом, по коду добавляются `assert` с проверкой. Задача - выловить отклонение как можно раньше.

Следующий способ - комментирование части кода до тех пор, пока код не будет падать. В какой то момент будет найдена строка, где падает.

И, конечно, рефакторинг, разделение кода на маленькие кусочки и тесты.

Comment: Здесь 80 тыс строк кода, только логическая часть.
+ сторонние библиотеки.
Рефакторинг займет год и не факт что вообще пройдет. Много ради производительности сделано, указатели, самописные контейнеры быстрого доступа, макросы и.т.д.
Ошибок несколько, и пока пытаешься одну вычислить возникает другая, при чем может в другом потоке быть. Если ставить выводы в консоль, то ошибок нет. Плюс взаимосвязь логическая между многими классами, что затрудняет комментирование кода для выявление ошибки. 

Пока единственный выход, это комментировать код и искать где инициализируются значения. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, `catch(...)` ловит только исключения С++, т.е. те которые были брошены с помощью `throw`.

В Visual C++, можно использовать опцию компиляции [`/EHa`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx). Тогда `catch(...)` будет также ловить системные и аппаратные исключения, в т.ч. ошибки доступа к памяти (#AV).